# How do I initialize a child json object in angular/typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a `model.ts` file.

```
export class MainClass {
    someVar: string;
    var2: string;
    subClass: SubClass;
    contact: ContactList;
}

export class SubClass {
  subItem: {
    item1: string;
    item2: string;
    item3: string;
  }
  constructor() {}
}


export class ContactList {
  itemList: ListItems[];
  constructor() {}
}


export class ListItems {
  list1: string;
  list2: string;
  list3: string;  
}
```

I have a `service.ts` file where I have setter methods I'm trying to update the model.

```
constructor(private model: SomeModel) {}

//some code

updateList(param1, param2, param3) {
    this.model.subClass.subItem.item1 = param1;//doesn't work
    this.model.contact.item[0].list1 = param2;//doesn't work
    this.model.someVar = param3;//works
}
```

It works for single variables but I get an error `Can't read property subItem of undefined` when trying to update subClass and contact. I know I have to initialize the subItem and itemList in the constructor of the model but I can't figure out the syntax. How can I initialize the model and update model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to initialize the constructor in the model like this

```
export class MainClass {
  someVar: string;
  var2: string;
  subClass: SubClass;
  contact: ContactList;
  constructor() {
    this.subClass = new SubClass();
    this.contact = new ContactList();
  }
}

export class SubClass {
  subItemVar: SubItem;
  constructor() {
    this.subItemVar = new SubItem();
  }
}

export class SubItem {
  item1: string;
  item2: string;
  item3: string;
}

export class ContactList {
  itemList: ListItems[];
  constructor() {
    this.itemList = new Array<ListItems>();
  }
}

export class ListItems {
  list1: string;
  list2: string;
  list3: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you are calling the constructor of the complex types you wish to initialize within your MainClass.

```
export class MainClass {
    someVar: string;
    var2: string;
    subClass: SubClass();
    contact: ContactList();
}
```

Note the parenthesis. If you have more complex initialization there are other angles we should look at too as you have several scenarios being described here. For instance within your SubClass you should ensure subItem has a constructor if you wish it to also be initialized when you spin up an instance of SubClass.

Another option for initializing subItem in your parent class is to do something like this in the constructor:

```
 constructor() {
        //... some init code
        this.subItem = new Array<SubItemModel>();
        this.subItem.push(new SubItemModel());
    }
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Initializing the variable within the model throws `TS1005: ';' expected, TS1109: Expression expected, TS1128: Declaration or statement expected`

Comment: Try `subClass = new SubClass();`.

Comment: @kratos24 - Did you do the same with `contact`?

Comment: Hmm.. Perhaps I poorly assumed you were passing in an initialized model? You must initialize the instance going into the method as a parameter (i.e. can't be a interface or similar). Assuming the complex types within the parent also have default constructors this should work without issue. Can you please include the supporting code in your question?

Comment: updated answer to include a way to ensure the subItem will have at least an element in the event it's default constructor doesn't handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Because **subClass** and **subItem** is undefined. You have to create new Instance for them before set value:

Change **SomeModel** to  **MainClass** or use **.map** function to mapping.

```
this.model.subClass = new SubClass();
this.model.subClass.subItem =  {item1:'123',item2: '222', item3: '333'};
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error is subClass ,subItem , contact are not  defined. To solve this change the models as follows

```
export class MainClass {
    someVar: string;
    var2: string;
    subClass: SubClass;
    contact: ContactList;
    constructor() {
      if(!this.subClass)
      this.subClass =new SubClass();
      if(!this.contact)
      this.contact =new ContactList();
    }
}

export class SubClass {
  subItem: SubItem;
  constructor() {
    if(!this.subItem)
     this.subItem =new SubItem();
  }
}
export class SubItem {

    item1: string;
    item2: string;
    item3: string;

  constructor() {}
}


export class ContactList {
  itemList: ListItems[]=[];
  constructor() {}
}
export class ListItems {
  list1: string;
  list2: string;
  list3: string;  
}
```

In service

```
constructor(private model: SomeModel) {}

//some code

updateList(param1, param2, param3) {
    this.model.subClass.subItem.item1 = param1;

 this.model.contact.itemList = [];
 let listItem: ListItems =new ListItems();
 listItem.list1 =param2
 this.model.contact.itemList.push(listItem)
    this.model.someVar = param3;
}
```

May this help you understand your mistakes and you can change the code according your requirement. Hope this will help.